# App stopped working if any other app communicate with internet

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to keep an AsyncTask running 24/7. It download some information from internet and then SMS it to relevant person. And check again after sending SMS if any new information is available. My phone has enough memory available to run my app. I found that within 3-5 hours app stop. After a long observation I figured it out that if any other app for example WhatsApp recieve or send any message then  my app stopped working. But it is not happening every time. It is very rare that my app stopped when any other app communicate with internet. Sometime I think that I am not figuring it out correctly that why app is stopped. It not gives any error when it stop. It seems that app simply finished its task and closed by itself. Here is my code how I am doing this. Please help me to figure out the problem.

```
Timer SMSTimer;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SMSTimer = new Timer();
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                if (runNewTask){
                    new RequestTask().execute(BaseUrl);
                    runNewTask =false;
                }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 5000);

}

public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        try {       
            // constants
            int timeoutSocket = 30000;
            int timeoutConnection = 30000;
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url[0]);
            HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(httpget);
            getResponse.addHeader("Cache-Control:", "no-cache");
            final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if(statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.w("MyApp", "Download Error: " + statusCode + "| for URL: " + url);
                return null;
            }
            String line = "";
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResponseEntity.getContent()));  

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
                total.append("\n");
            }
            line = total.toString();
            return line;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;

        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try {
            if(result != null) {
                CreatMsg(result);

            }
                runNewTask = true;
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            runNewTask = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an AsynchTask? Surely you should be using a service? Also a bootreceiver as well to restart your task after a reboot?

Comment: From the AsyncTask documentation: AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.

Comment: I did not know about the things you guys just said. If you please provide me link to any tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Alarm Manager now to repeat the task and it is working like a charm.

```
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private AlarmManager manager;

    private void setRecurringAlarm(Context context) {


        manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 10000;
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
      //  Toast.makeText(this, "Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

And here is receiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // start the download

                if (MainActivity.runNewTask){
                    MainActivity.runNewTask = false;
                    MainActivity.StartServer();

                }

        }
    }
```